# Are exponential algorithms (with very small exponents) faster than the general logarithmic algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity

Say something runs at n^0.5 vs log n. It's true that this obviously isn't fast (the log n beats it). However, what about n^0.1 or n^0.01? Would it still be preferable to go with the logarithmic algorithm?

I guess, how small should the exponent be to switch to exponential?

Comment: what do you mean by exponential here? When we refer to exponential complexity, its of the form c^n, like 1.1^n rather than n^c, like n^1.1

Comment: n^0.5 is polynomial time, not exponential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exponent does not matter.  It is `n` that matters.

No matter how small the exponent of an exponential-time-complexity algorithm is, the logarithmic-time-complexity algorithm will beat it if `n` is large enough.

So, it all depends on your `n`.  Substitute a specific `n`, calculate the actual run-time cost of your exponential-time-complexity algorithm vs your logarithmic-time-complexity algorithm, and see who the winner is.

Comment: Yes, but n^0.1 isn't exponential -- it's sub-linear.

Comment: @PaulHankin good point.  So, I suppose the OP meant `n^1.1` and `n^1.01` then?

Comment: They're probably just confused about the terminology

Comment: I don't know what he meant. n^1.1 isn't exponential either though -- it's between linear and quadratic. Exponential looks like 1.1^n with the n being the exponent.

Answer (score 2):

Asymptotic complexity can be a bit misleading.

A function that's proportional to log *n* will be less than one that's proportional to (say) *n*<sup>0.01</sup> . . . once *n* gets large enough.

But for smaller values of *n*, all bets are off, because the constant of proportionality can play a large role. For example, sorting algorithms that have *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) worst-case complexity are often better choices, when *n* is known to be small, than sorting algorithms that have *O*(*n* log *n*), because the latter are typically more complicated and therefore have more overhead. It's only when *n* grows larger that the latter start to win out.

In general, performance decisions should be based on profiling and testing, rather than on purely mathematical arguments about what *should theoretically* be faster.

Answer (score 2):

In general, given two sublinear algorithms you should choose the one with the smallest constant multiplier. Since complexity theory won't help you with that, you will have to write the programs as efficiently as possible and benchmark them. This necessity might lead you to choose the algorithm which is easier to code efficiently, which might also be a reasonable criterion.

This is of course not the case with superlinear functions, where large n exaggerate costs. But even then, you might find an algorithm whose theoretical efficiency is superior but which requires a very large n to be superior to a simpler algorithm, perhaps so large that it will never be tried.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about big O which tends to refer to how an algorithm scales as a function of inputs, as opposed to how fast it is in the absolute time sense. On certain data sets an algorithm with a worse big O, may perform much better in absolute time.

Let's say you have two algorithms, one is exactly O(n^0.1) and the other is exactly log(n)

Though the O(n^0.1) is worse, it takes until n is about equal to 100,000,000,000 for it to be surpassed by log(n).

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm could plausibly have a sqrt(N) running time, but what would one with an even lower exponent look like? It is an obvious candidate for replacing a logarithmic method if such can be found, and that's where big O analysis ceases to be useful - it depends on N and the other costs of each operation, plus implementation difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, exponential complexity is in the form of [image: e^n], where *n* is the exponent. Complexities below [image: n] are generally called sub-linear.

Yes, from some finite *n₀* onwards, general logarithm is always better than any [image: n^k]. However, as you observe, this *n₀* turns out to be quite large for smaller values of *k*. Therefore, if you expect your value of *n* to be reasonably small, the payload of the logarithm may be worse than the power, but here we move from theory to practice.

To see why should the logarithm be better, let's first look at some plots:

[image: n^{0.5}-\ln{n}]
[image]

This curve looks mostly the same for all values of *k*, but may cross the *n* axis for smaller exponents. If its value is above 0, the logarithm is smaller and thus better. The point at which it crosses the axis for the second time (not in this graph) is where the logarithm becomes the best option for all values of *n* after that.

Notice the minimum - if the minimum exists and is below 0, we can assume that the function will eventually cross the axis for the second time and become in favour of the logarithm. So let's find the minimum, using the derivative.

[image: (n^k-\ln{n})'=0]

[image: kn^{k-1}-1/n=0]

[image: n=k^{-1/k}]

From the nature of the function, this is the minimum and it always exists. Therefore, the function is rising from this point.

For *k = 0.1*, this turns out to be 10,000,000,000, and this is not even where the function crosses the *n* axis for the second time, only the minimum is there. So in practise, using the exponent is better than the logarithm at least up to this point (unless you have some constants there, of course).